# Add key value pairs to an existing pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create series that will be appended to a larger dataframe. Basically, i immediately know what the first two columns(PartNumber, and SerialNumber) should equal. I then need to loop through a file to find all of the remaining ordered pairs that should be in their own columns on that same line. The file is formatted as follows:

```
Name of the file is the Serial Number
Column1 Name=Value
Column2 Name=Value
Column3 Name=Value
```

```
def main()
    for serial in serialList:
        df = df.append(processSerialNumber(cs4Dir, fileName, serial.strip()))
    return df


def processSerialNumber(dir, partNumber, serial):
    printEvent('processSerialNumber, ' + partNumber + ', ' + serial)
    with open(os.path.join(dir, serial + '.csv'), 'r') as s:
        cs4Lines = s.readlines()
        lineInfo = {'PartNumber' : partNumber,
                    'SerialNumber' : serial}
        for l in cs4Lines:
            line = l.strip()
            lineSplit = line.split('=')
            lineInfo = lineInfo.append(lineSplit[0] : [lineSplit[1]])
    return lineInfo
```

my goal is to end up with a series(lineInfo)(or any other variable containing key value pairs) that i can easily append to a dataframe.

the above code is returning the error:

```
lineInfo = lineInfo.append(lineSplit[0] : lineSplit[1])
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have had success in the past building series' but I can not figure out how to add key value pairs to an existing series in a loop.

Comment: So is your question around how to build the dictionary from these lists ? Also, could you please post use this as guidance to modify your question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for that link, very helpful. My question was how to add a key-value pair. I thought it was a pandas.series object i was using instead of a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add curly brackets around the key-value pair

```
lineInfo = lineInfo.append({lineSplit[0] : lineSplit[1]})
                           ^                           ^
```